# need help in using get_the_tag_list($ID) WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am making a new WordPress template and I want to just get, in text format, the list of tags associated with a post. I am using

```
get_the_tag_list($id)
```

But the problem is that it returns the URL as well as the text. Is there any way to just get the "text" of tags attached to a post seperated by a comma ?

i.e. **tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4** etc without the URL and just as text?

Thanks

Comment: Same question here:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/271945?replies=2

Answer (score 2):

The template tag [get_the_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_tags) returns an array of all of the tags associated with the post currently in-context within the Loop. You could traverse this array and generate a comma-separated list by hand.

Here's an example of how you could do it using the implode and print_r functions:

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach ($posttags as $tag) {
     $tagnames[count($tagnames)] = $tag->name;
  }
  $comma_separated_tagnames = implode(", ", $tagnames);
  print_r($comma_separated_tagnames);
}
?>
```

Comment: hey - this is perfect but it returns ALL the tags - not just the tags for a post ?

Comment: any ideas how to get it to return tags JUST for a single post ?

Comment: The code above *will* return the tags for a single post if you put it in the Loop for a single post. You don't send get_the_tags an ID, so it's context sensitive. If you're using this code in a more global context, you could test against $tag->term_id within the foreach to filter out the tags you're not interested in.

Comment: thanks again for the response - the problem i am facing when i use this code is that tags are "aggregated"

i.e. it prints tags at the top post fine - only the top post tags appear, but then in the 2nd post - it prints the top post tags and the second post tags and so on. third post, 1st, 2nd and 3rd post tags etc etc

how to restrict tags in this code, to just show for one post ?

Comment: i.e. this code works perfect

<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
foreach($posttags as $tag) {
echo $tag->name . ' '; 
}
}
?>

and it returns only the tags for each post. yours work great - since i can print $comma_separate_tagnames in echo - but I'm not a PHP coder so not sure how to change the code to not make to "count up / aggregate" the tags - and instead just show tags per individual post

Comment: add $tagnames = array(); before the foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
foreach($posttags as $tag) {
echo $tag->name . ','; 
}
}
?>
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_tags

Comment: I missed that it is nearly identical to Evan's reply. It should still work as requested inside the Loop.

On my own blog I use the_tags( ' ', ', ', ''); to print a list of tags out after the post title. Those are with links inclusive though so I guess it is not useful for you.