# Unable to get get_the_tags() in Wordpress Template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using this code to get the tags in my wordpress posts for a theme

```
`<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach ($posttags as $tag) {
     $tagnames[count($tagnames)] = $tag->name;
  }
  $comma_separated_tagnames = implode(", ", $tagnames);
  print_r($comma_separated_tagnames);
}
?>`
```

The PROBLEM is that it is returning tags for "all posts" not just individual posts, and I think the problem is that if a post DOESNT have tags - it just inserts tags anyway.

Can anyone help modify this so:

> 1. It return tags only for a post - not all tags
> 2. If there are no tags for a post, dont return anything

P.S - [Can check out here for the wordpress docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_tags)

Comment: Please don't repost questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880673/wordpress-getthetaglistid-help

Comment: thanks again for the response - the problem i am facing when i use this code is that tags are "aggregated" i.e. it prints tags at the top post fine - only the top post tags appear, but then in the 2nd post - it prints the top post tags and the second post tags and so on. third post, 1st, 2nd and 3rd post tags etc etc how to restrict tags in this code, to just show for one post ? – Andy 46 mins ago

Comment: i.e. this code works perfect <?php $posttags = get_the_tags(); if ($posttags) { foreach($posttags as $tag) { echo $tag->name . ' '; } } ?> and it returns only the tags for each post. yours work great - since i can print $comma_separate_tagnames in echo - but I'm not a PHP coder so not sure how to change the code to not make to "count up / aggregate" the tags - and instead just show tags per individual post – Andy 19 mins ago

Answer (score 3):

```
<footer class="entry-footer">
                    <?php //get all tags for the post
                    $t = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
                    echo "<p class='tags-list'>TAGGED WITH: ";
                    foreach ($t as $tag) {
                        $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);
                    echo "<a href='$tag_link' class='used-tag' rel='tag'>".($tag->name)."</a>&nbsp;";
                    }
                    echo "</p>";
                    ?>
                    </footer>
```

This is what I did, displays tags for each post in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
<?php the_tags(); ?>
```

Inside the '[Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)'.

[Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_tags)

Comment: the_tags(); will force you to echo the tags and it's links their is cases developer need only tags name or tag link separately .

Answer (score -1):

alright I hope this could help someone , I stuck on this issue for about hour 
 trying to get tags of my post "so I can mix it with twitter share link "
 the_tags(); function were useless since I use it out of WP loop , get_the_tag_list(); were perfect to me since it can include post id ,

```
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID; 

$posttags =  strip_tags( get_the_tag_list( ' ', '', '', "$postid" ) ) ;
```

^^ the above code I stripped html codes to get tag name without href link .

this is the function use case :-

```
get_the_tag_list( string $before = '', string $sep = '', string $after = '', int $id )
```