# Wordpress - get_the_tag_list - only text!

Tags: php, wordpress

I need an script that will output only the tags text from the post tags. Not with links, ul's and other stuff, just plain text so I can add this text as a class of the post.
Can anybody help? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Founded the answer here:
[need help in using get_the_tag_list($ID) WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880673/wordpress-get-the-tag-listid-help)

```
<?php
   $posttags = get_the_tags();
   if ($posttags) {
      foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->name . ' '; 
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: This would be a good use for [wp_list_pluck](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck):
 `$posttags = get_the_tags(); if($posttags) { echo implode(' ', wp_list_pluck($posttags, 'name'); }`

Answer (score 1):

I needed the tag list for my meta data, here's how I assembled the string:

```
echo implode( ',', array_map( function( $tag ){
   return $tag->name;
}, get_the_tags() ) );
```

this results in a comma separated tag list that can be used in the meta tags. You can remove the comma or course

Answer (score -1):

You can list the tags using the `get_the_tag_list` method.

```
<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_tag_list('',' , ','')); ?>
```

See the [WordPress Codex docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tag_list) for more details.